# Is there MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, libraries, msdn

Is there MSDN Library for `Visual Studio 2010`?

What is the lastest version of `MSDN Library`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it is very different to the MSDN library in VS 2008.

It is an optional install and you select which libraries you want (.net, web, informs etc.) it then checks for latest versions and installs.

However, it is just a database and web server, to actually browse, you use a standard web browser. The library is automatically launched to the correct page when you press f1 from within Visual Studio

Comment: In VS use Help | Manage Help Settings to configure and check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Well no, not in the traditional sense as seen in 2008. VS 2010 moved to a new help system which heavily relies on Internet, so there is no classical MSDN Library for 2010.