# Is there MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: libraries, visual-studio-2012, msdn

Is there MSDN Library for `Visual Studio 2012` like `Visual Studio 2008`? Or it is the same with [Visual Studio 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/227591/is-there-msdn-library-for-visual-studio-2010)? I couldn't find any information on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one MSDN library. The MSDN library has expanded considerably since VS 2008 and now contains information about all Microsoft products.

[This archived URL](https://web.archive.org/web/20130110180415/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa187916.aspx) should get you started.  Note that the current Microsoft doc/URL no longer includes information on older Visual Studio releases.